# Exact inverse of pandas' "pivot" operation

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, melt

I have a pandas dataframe in the rough format

```
print(df)
    Time  GroupA  GroupB  Value1  Value2
0  100.0     1.0     1.0    18.0     0.0
1  100.0     1.0     2.0    16.0     0.0
2  100.0     2.0     1.0    18.0     0.0
3  100.0     2.0     2.0    10.0     0.0
```

where `Time` is a count variable / timestamp, `GroupA` and `GroupB` are categories, and `Value1` and `Value2` are numerical quantities. This code snippet creates a mockup dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
values = np.zeros(shape=(4,5))
values[:,0] = 100
values[:,1] = [1]*2 + [2]*2
values[:,2] = [1,2]*2
values[:,3] = np.random.randint(low=10,high=20,size=(4))
df = pd.DataFrame(values,columns=['Time','GroupA','GroupB','Value1','Value2'])
```

After loading in some data, I want to calculate and fill in values of `Value2`. As it happens (since, incidentally, `Value2` is a time series function of `Value1` within each existing (`GroupA`, `GroupB`) pair), I found it easiest to calculate these values by first pivoting my data into the form:

```
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index='Time',columns=['GroupA','GroupB'],values=['Value1','Value2'], fill_value=0.0)
```

Then after some unrelated code I have filled in values

```
print(df_pivot)
       Value1             Value2            
GroupA    1.0     2.0        1.0     2.0    
GroupB    1.0 2.0 1.0 2.0    1.0 2.0 1.0 2.0
Time                                        
100.0      13  16  16  10     27  20  28  20
```

Now I want to "unpivot" this back to the original format of `df`. I could do this manually by looping over `df`, looking up the value in `df_pivot`, and filling it, but I'd prefer to use built-in functions. Try as I might using variations of `df.melt`, I cannot perform this inversion, because of problems with `df_pivot`'s hierarchical columns. My best attempt is

```
dfm = df_pivot.reset_index().melt(id_vars="Time")
dfm.columns.values[1] = "HACK"
dfm = dfm.pivot_table(index=["Time","GroupA","GroupB"],columns="HACK",values="value").reset_index()
```

which produces the data frame

```
print(dfm)
HACK   Time  GroupA  GroupB  Value1  Value2
0     100.0     1.0     1.0      13      27
1     100.0     1.0     2.0      16      20
2     100.0     2.0     1.0      16      28
3     100.0     2.0     2.0      10      20
```

This works, but doesn't strike me as be best solution, or very portable (why does melt produce a "NaN" column name? why do I have a manually find the index of this column and rename it? why do I have to pivot to undo a pivot?) Experimenting and looking through documentation and examples for an alternative, I'm at a loss, though. The `melt` function has a `col_level` argument that looks like it should help, but any valid value I use for this just leads to data loss (losing the "Time", "GroupA", or "GroupB" data).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `stack` is more straightforward

```
df_pivot.stack([1,2]).reset_index()
Out[8]: 
    Time  GroupA  GroupB  Value1  Value2
0  100.0     1.0     1.0      13       0
1  100.0     1.0     2.0      13       0
2  100.0     2.0     1.0      12       0
3  100.0     2.0     2.0      11       0
```

Comment: I agree with you.